# Update Item Unit Costs using SQL (Multiple Items)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has multiple columns.
2 of the columns in this table are item_no and Unit_Cost

The unit cost has to be changed for 100 different articles.
I want to write a SQL query to update all 100 articles with their new Unit_Cost.

Update should be applied only to the unit cost column,keeping data on all the other columns un touched

Thank you,

Comment: `update my_table set unit_cost = [new value] where [condition...]`

Comment: update tablename set unit_cost = _newvalue_ where somecondition

Comment: Thanks,How do I update this for 100 articles?,

Comment: You have to specify a WHERE condition that includes those 100 articles (only).

Comment: Do they all have different `unit_cost` values?

Comment: Would be good if you could provide sample data.

Comment: These 100 articles have different unit costs.Like ItemA=20,ItemB=12,ItemC=32

Comment: What is the condition, upon which you decide what records to update?

Comment: Then you may as well use 100 different queries...

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect the result?

Comment: update Item_Table
Set unit_cost=20,12,32
where item_no in ('A','B','C') . There are about 100 Items,Can I use a similar query?

Comment: @Sequel3 I write an answer you can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you can try to use `Update` with `CASE WHEN`.

Write your condition in `CASE WHEN`

```
update Item_Table 
Set unit_cost=(
    CASE WHEN item_no = 'A' THEN 20 
         WHEN item_no = 'B' THEN 12
         WHEN item_no = 'C' THEN 32
    END
)
where item_no in ('A','B','C')
```

Here is some sample

```
create table Item_Table (
      item_no varchar(50),
    unit_cost int

);

insert into Item_Table values ('A',1);
insert into Item_Table values ('B',1);
insert into Item_Table values ('C',1);
insert into Item_Table values ('D',1);

update Item_Table 
Set unit_cost=(
    CASE WHEN item_no = 'A' THEN 20 
         WHEN item_no = 'B' THEN 12
         WHEN item_no = 'C' THEN 32
    END
)
where item_no in ('A','B','C')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM Item_Table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8776f/1/0)**:

```
| item_no | unit_cost |
|---------|-----------|
|       A |        20 |
|       B |        12 |
|       C |        32 |
|       D |         1 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the Query
When I try to run the query

I get a new error message

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Unit_Cost', table Item'; column does not allow nulls. 

What does this actually mean?
My Unit_Cost Values are 1.02,3.45,5.6

I dont see any "Null" values

Comment: Found the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE <table> SET <column> = <value> WHERE <condition>
```

Note that the condition is optional and you don't have to provide one if you would like to apply the update to all records in the table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html